# Django Rest framework always return error 400

Tags: python, django, retrofit

I'm trying to use a Post method that returns a token for authentication when someone post the correct username and password, but everytime I get the 400 error (I'm tryin to use RetroFit for Android)

Here are my urls (I'm usin tokken authentication):

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as tmp

from decaught import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', tmp.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

And here's how I use retrofit:

The POST method:

```
 @POST("/api-auth/")
    Call<Tokken> get_tokken(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

The login method:

```
 private void signIn() {
        boolean isValid = validate();
        if (isValid) {

            mService.get_tokken(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Tokken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Tokken> call, Response<Tokken> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        System.out.println("Te lo imprimo");
                        System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "tokken recibido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        int statusCode = response.code();
                        // handle request errors depending on status code
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Tokken> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error al recibir tokken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

                }
            });
            /*startActivity(new Intent(this, RolSelection.class));*/
        }
    }
```

But every time I try to log in in the server I get this message:

> [16/Apr/2018 20:56:06] "POST /api-auth/?username=admin&password=admin1234HTTP/1.1" 400 79

Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

In major possibility you sets the [`DEBUG`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#debug) flag on the settings to `False` and concorrently you not sets the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts). While you run project on the debug mode Django don't check [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) but when this flag change to `False` Django compare your project host and if this host not found on the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) list raising error 400.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand anything that you are saying

Comment: In settings.py file change `DEBUG = True`, if your problem solved read more about Django `ALLOWED_HOSTS` config.

Comment: @Green_Sam all thing is ok?